# Easy way to do data entry in windows store app

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8.1

I'm doing a simple windows 8 store app, and I would like to have a simple double click(tap) to edit.

I was thinking something along the lines of;

```
void editProducer(object sender, DoubleTappedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var t = new TextBox() {FontSize = 48, Width = 600, DataContext = DataModel.Producer};
    var f = new Flyout() {Content = t};
    f.ShowAt((FrameworkElement)sender);
}
```

But I have not been able to get a version of that working.

What did I miss(I've tried unsuccessfully to add binding)? Or is it totally wrong to try and do it this way?

Update;

this code almost seemed like it was going to work, and was closer to the original direction, but still didn't work;

```
var srcTextBlock = sender as TextBox;
var d = srcTextBlock.GetBindingExpression(TextBlock.TextProperty);
var t = new TextBlock() { FontSize = 48, Width = 200 };
t.SetBinding(TextBlock.TextProperty, d.ParentBinding);
var f = new Flyout() { Content = t };
f.ShowAt((FrameworkElement)sender);
```

so I eventually went with something like this for now, based on the direction suggested;

```
var tb = (TextBox) sender;
tb.IsReadOnly = false;
tb.SelectedText = tb.Text;
tb.LostFocus += (o, args) => { tb.IsReadOnly = true; };
```

Answer (score 0):

A simpler way of doing this is to use a simple TextBox with a custom style which looks like a `TextBlock` when it is disable (`IsEnabled` is false).

So then you just have to attach this event to your text fields to make it work (on double tap) :

```
void editProducer(object sender, DoubleTappedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
  (sender as TexBlock).IsEnabled = ! (sender as TexBlock).IsEnabled
}
```

Comment: Post a more complete example. I was unable to get that to work, but sounds like it might.

Comment: The problem, as best I can tell, is if the control is not enabled, the doubleTap doesnt fire

Comment: From MSDN : "Elements that are not enabled do not participate in hit testing or focus and therefore will not be sources of input events."
I'll take a look a it.